# Testing OWIN Middleware in ASP.NET WebApi 2: How to set cookies?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, cookies, owin

I'm trying to test an OWIN Middleware component in an ASP.NET WebApi 2 application. The middleware is supposed to look at the cookies of the incoming request, modify some stuff on the request before it's handed to the next component, and potentially set a cookie on the way out as well.

What's tripping me up is that the `OwinRequest.Cookies` property is of type [`RequestCookieCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn308198%28v%3dvs.113%29), which doesn't seem to allow modifying, and the property itself is read-only which means I can't use the `RequestCookieCollection(IDictionary<string,string>)` constructor to initialize a collection with cookies already in it and set that on the request.

I want do do something like this:

```
var context = new OwinContext();
// option 1:
context.Request.Cookies.Append("cookie-name", "cookie-value");
// option 2:
var cookies = new RequestCookieCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>{ { "cookie-name", "cookie-value" } });
context.Request.Cookies = cookies;

await myMiddleware.Invoke(context);

// Assert stuff about context.Response
```

but that doesn't work for aforementioned reasons.

I had hoped not to have to mock `IOwinContext` entierly, because it's quite convenient to have it set up with well-functioning `Request` and `Response` objects (I need to, among other things, look at `Request.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` in my implementation).

Comment: Give an example of how the context is to be used when exercising the test. Mocking the context is a simple matter depending on what is needed for the test

Comment: Otherwise you can use an in-memory integration test with TestServer if you want access to the full pipeline.

Comment: @Nkosi: Is the provided example of what I'd like to do not enough? My middleware basically does the following: 1. check for existence of a cookie on the incoming request. if the cookie exists, use its value to set a header, so that the pipline after this component thinks the header was always present. 2. call the next component. 3. on the way out, check for some conditions, and possibly set a cookie value.

Comment: I am curious about how the middleware is defined as that would determine how to create and exercise the middleware. I have already worked out the gist of the flow you included in the OP. Your last comment makes it even clearer than the example I was plannign to show so I will update that. The last sticking point is the middleware definition itself.

Comment: It's often easier to move YOUR code into separate class. And unit test your class would be much easier. Also in such cases you still need to check that this middleware is connected properly. If you have integration or api tests it may be enough to have few unit tests for your coockieService and integration test that this middleware is working as expected

Answer (score 1):

Using the following as the subject of an example middleware for unit testing

```
using RequestDelegate = Func<IOwinContext, Task>;

class MyMiddleware {
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context) {
        //The middleware is supposed to look at the cookies of the incoming request, 
        var request = context.Request;
        var authenticated = request.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

        var cookies = request.Cookies;
        if (cookies["cookie-name"] != null) {
            // 1. check for existence of a cookie on the incoming request. 
            //if the cookie exists, use its value to set a header, 
            //so that the pipline after this component thinks the header was always present.
            request.Headers.Append("header-name", "header-value");
        }

        //2. call the next component.
        await next.Invoke(context);

        //3. on the way out, check for some conditions, and possibly set a cookie value.
        if (authenticated) {
            context.Response.Cookies.Append("cookie-name", "cookie-value");
        }
    }
}
```

and using the details provided about the desired behavior,

it would be difficult to unit test the controller with all the plumbing needed for a full `OwinContext`.

You have already stated a lot of the limitations around accessing some of the members.

Owin however provides many abstractions that would allow for the desired behavior to be mock/stubbed/faked for an isolated unit test.

The following example is based on the subject provided above, and uses the `Moq` mocking framework along with concrete implementations to properly setup and exercise an isolated unit test for the subject middleware.

```
[TestClass]
public class OwinMiddlewareCookiesTest {
    [Test]
    public async Task MyMiddleware_Should_Set_RequestHeader_And_ResponseHeader() {
        //Arrange
        var cookieStore = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "cookie-name", "cookie-value" } };
        var cookies = new RequestCookieCollection(cookieStore);

        var request = Mock.Of<IOwinRequest>();
        var requestMock = Mock.Get(request);
        requestMock.Setup(_ => _.Cookies).Returns(cookies);
        requestMock.Setup(_ => _.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);
        requestMock.Setup(_ => _.Headers.Append(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()));

        var response = new OwinResponse();

        var context = Mock.Of<OwinContext>();
        var contextMock = Mock.Get(context);
        contextMock.CallBase = true;
        contextMock.Setup(_ => _.Request).Returns(request);
        contextMock.Setup(_ => _.Response).Returns(response);

        RequestDelegate next = _ => Task.FromResult((object)null);

        var myMiddleware = new MyMiddleware(next);

        //Act
        await myMiddleware.Invoke(context);

        //Assert
        requestMock.Verify(_ => _.Headers.Append("header-name", "header-value"));
        response.Headers.ContainsKey("Set-Cookie");
    }
}
```

Only the necessary dependencies needed to be mocked for the test to flow to completion and the expected behavior verified.

And since the request implementation's `Cookies` property was not able to be overridden, the abstraction had to be used. This however provided greater flexibility in mocking the desired behavior.

Comment: I was hoping I'd be able to avoid all this mocking ceremony; after all, I want the regular behavior for everything but cookies. But maybe that's impossible.

Comment: @TomasAschan have you tried using TestServer to see if you could tap into the cookies collection during an in-memory integration test? Short of an actual running server that is the only other scenario where the full framework/pipeline will be in play that I am aware of.

Comment: I have (lots of) other tests exercising this code with the `TestServer` approach; this question is about _unit_ testing this specific component _without_ the full pipeline. Since the component is supposed to modify both incoming and outgoing requests, I want to verify that it does so correctly without having to hook up a bunch of other things as well. Mocking all relevant parts of the `IOwinContext` works, but I feel it ties the test too much to the implementation (i.e. only mocked behavior is available, so if I change _how_ I achieve the goals, I also have to change the mock setup).